# openhtf, repeat testcase even when passed

Tags: python-3.x

In the spintop-openhtf framework every testcase can be repeated. But that would mean the testcase is considered failed and is therefore repeated.
How can a test be repeated with several numbers?

Answer (score 0):

One way I found is the following:

```
def main():

    global test_nr            # pylint: disable=global-statement

    for i in custom_range:
        test_nr = i
        plan.execute()

def trigger():

    global test_nr

    test.state['test_nr'] = test_nr
```

That way the variable can be passed through to the testcases.
This works for me. if you have better suggestions please do share.